# Using GStreamer to receive and send h264 video (from OBS)

Tags: ffmpeg, gstreamer

I've been trying to set up using [GStreamer](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org) to get support for some input I can output from OBS.

**OBS:** rtp_mpegts to udp://localhost:5000

```
http-launch 8080 webmmux streamable=true name=stream udpsrc uri=udp://localhost:5000 caps="application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)MP2T-ES, payload=(int)
33" ! gstrtpjitterbuffer latency=200 ! application/x-rtp ! rtpmp2tdepay ! video/mpegts ! mpegtsdemux ! video/x-h264 ! queue ! decodebin ! vp8enc ! stream.   audiotestsrc ! vorbisenc ! stream.
```

However, using this it seems to accept connections, but just closes them again after a while. Any clues on what I am doing wrong? I am open to any format changes as long as they're supported by OBS / ffmpeg.

As a bonus, how do I add support for audio as well?

### Background

I've found https://github.com/sdroege/http-launch, which works well in displaying a GStreamer video over http:

```
<video id="video" autoplay="autoplay" controls="">
    <source src="https://localhost:8080" type="video/mp4" codecs="avc1.4D401E, mp4a.40.2">
    You browser doesn't support element <code>video</code>.
</video>
```

I've managed to set up a pipeline where I can use a GStreamer source to pipe into a http-launch 
pipeline and display it on video:

```
http-launch 8080 webmmux streamable=true name=stream udpsrc port=5000 caps = "application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264, payload=(int)96" ! mpegtsdemu
x ! h264parse ! TIViddec2 ! videoconvert ! vp8enc ! stream.   audiotestsrc ! vorbisenc ! stream.

gst-launch-1.0 -v videotestsrc ! videoconvert ! x264enc tune=zerolatency bitrate=500 speed-preset=superfast ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000
```

However, I don't think [OBS](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org) supports rpt over UDP. It uses ffmpeg to send these packets, which **can** stream rtp_mpegts. I've found some [code snippets](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/gstreamer-devel/2011-January.txt) which claim to support the format, and stitch together the above pipeline.